# How to make score appear on GUI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game, and I'm having trouble making the score appear on the game.

So far, this is all I have:

```
public class keepingScore : MonoBehaviour {
    public static double homeScore;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        double homeScore = 5.0;
        print(homeScore);
    }
}
```

So my code is printing 5 to the console, and when I've tried other methods, it says it wont work because homeScore is not a string.

Any help guys?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps parse it to string first? using `homescore.toString()`

Comment: What other methods have you tried? `print` will always print to the console and never the screen.

Comment: @Barak I added this at the bottom: 
  private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), homeScore.toString());
    }

Error CS1061 'double' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'double' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: its not `toString`, it should be `ToString` with upper case of T

Comment: You really should just go watch the [Roll-A-Ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial), it goes over the basics like displaying text on screen very well. Also, Do not use `OnGUI` that is ment to be used for custom editor componets only, the tutorial will show the correct way to do it with a `Text` component.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use GUI:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html

or you can try Canvas GUI that must better:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html

Answer (score 0):

So first of all what you need if you want to have score in your GUI is to have a `Text` component in your scene.

Once you have your `Text` component in your scene you need to create a script that will handle the score and add it to the `Text` component you have created. This is an example of a Score manager script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class keepingScore : MonoBehaviour {

    public static double homeScore;

    Text text;

    void Awake () {

        text = GetComponent<Text>();

        homeScore = 0.0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        text.text = "Score: " + homeScore;

    }
}
```

Now you can attach this script to the `Text` component you have created earlier. What this script does is first retreive the `Text` component that it is attached too and initialize a `public static double homeScore` that you can access and modify from any script by just doing `keepingScore.homeScore`. Finally the `Update` function will run every frame to update the `Text` component you have.

Now that you have a `Text` component in your scene with this script attached to it, you can start modifying the value of your score. From wherever you want. An example would be let's say when your player picks up a coin you want to give him 1 point, so if the player collides with the coin you add 1 to the `homeScore`

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

    if (collision.CompareTag("Coin"))
        keepingScore.homeScore++;
}
```

This would for example add 1 to the score when the player collides with the coin.

You can do `keepingScore.homeScore += pointAmount` wherever you want to add points to the player and it will automatically update the GUI `Text`.